# Django static files resolving after collectstatic

Tags: python, django

I have run

> python manage.py collectstatic

so I have copies of my static files in "/static" folder.

But now Django uses files from /static/myapp/js/myapp.js, not from myapp/static/myapp/js/myapp.js

what should I change to resolve myapp/static/myapp/js/myapp.js first?

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Add the location you want it to look in at the top of the STATICFILES_DIR list?

Comment: but what if I have more then one app? I dont think it is a good idea to add location of every static app folder... May be there is a more convenient way?

Comment: Go read the Django tutorial and docs on how to manage static files. It is pretty comprehensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders):

> The Default value of `STATICFILES_FINDERS` is:

```
[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

> The default will find files stored in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting (using django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder) and in a static subdirectory of each app (using django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder). If multiple files with the same name are present, the first file that is found will be used.

So, in your `settings.py`, add this:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
]
```

Basically what we are doing is overriding `STATICFILES_FINDERS` by swapping the default entries, so that `AppDirectoriesFinder` is used first.